# Есть таблица с Display Name, как скормить в PowerShell табличку и выявить кто enabled, а кто disabled accounts? Exchange

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server, exchange

Всем привет! Вот такая задача. Есть таблица с Display Name, как скормить в PowerShell табличку и выявить кто enabled, а кто disabled  accounts?
Пробовал так:

---

> Import-CSV -path C:\Users\GKozlov\Desktop\tw.csv -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach-Object {
> $User = $_.DisplayName
> Get-Mailbox $User | ft Alias
> }

---

Выдает ошибку:

---

> At line:1 char:218
> ...                                                   Get-Mailbox $User | ...
> ~~~~~~~~~~~
> Unexpected token 'Get-Mailbox' in expression or statement.
> CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

---

В чем ошибка, что добавить?

Comment: А можно пример таблицы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

```
$Users = Import-CSV -path "C:\Users\GKozlov\Desktop\tw.csv" -Encoding UTF8 
  foreach ($User in $Users) {
     $Out = ($User.DisplayName).Trim()
     Get-ADUser -filter {name -eq $Out} -server alf | select name,enabled 
}
```

---

Так получилось

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]